# is my head retopo okay?

Tags: retopology

i would like some feedback and guidance on my first attempt at retopology I'm especially struggling with lips

this is my base sculpt
[image: base mesh]

this is my retopo mesh[image]
[image]
[image]

here it is subdivided and smoothed [image]

Comment: it looks rather good, what is the problem with the lips?

Comment: thank you! i feel like my retopologized lips look nothing like the actual lips I sculpted and it will be weird when I bake the normals. i had no idea how to join the center line of the lips, should all the vertices connect there or should their be an opening?

Comment: Looks like you're losing a lot of detail in the lips.  I'm not that experienced in this area, but maybe this is where you'd bake the normals from the high poly and reproject them onto the low poly

Comment: if you plan to open the mouth you should extrude inwards the mouth hole

Comment: oh yes, i totally forgot i had to make a inward mouth